# MySQL - SQLSTATE Values

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, signals, sqlexception

I created a procedure in which if the input is equal to 0, the procedure will throw an SQLException with an error message of 'dwa'.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE enter_the_dragon(test INT)

BEGIN

  DECLARE test_error CONDITION FOR SQLSTATE '42123';

  IF test = 0 THEN

    SIGNAL test_error
      SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'dwa';

  END IF;

END;
```

I am aware that SQLSTATE value '00000' means there's no error and SQLSTATE that starts with '01' is a warning. Does that mean that every SQLSTATE that doesn't collide with these two rules is an error?
Considering this rules, are there any other rules on SQLSTATE? Format? Or I am free to create my own SQLSTATE (ex. 01123 (warning) etc.)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Had the same problem, look at: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/signal.html

= '00' (success)

= '01' (warning)

= '02' (not found)

> '02' (exception)